# Skip inserting data in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got getter which gets list of my `FilterModelRow`. If condition is null I want to skip inserting the data into the list and the best do it inline

```
 get getFilterRows {
    return [FilterRowModel(Icon(Icons.title), 'Age', 'equal', age),
            FilterRowModel(Icon(Icons.title), 'Age', 'min', minAge),
            FilterRowModel(Icon(Icons.title), 'Age', 'max', maxAge)
           ];

  }
```

I tried

```
...
age != null FilterRowModel(Icon(Icons.title), 'Age', 'equal', age): null
...
```

But that insert null which ends with an error. So how to completely skip adding line into the list if condition is met

**Simplified version**

```
  var age = null;

  List<int> myList = [age!=null ? age : null];

  print(myList); //--> return [null] and I want to return empty list []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tell to your list to insert a null value, it will.

Now you have two options :

1 - You can instantiate your list and add values that are not null

```
List<int> myList = [];
if (age != null) myList.add(age);
```

2 - You can remove null values from your list with removeWhere method

```
myList.removeWhere((value) => value == null);
```

Comment: Thanks... I also thought this will be the only way. I was hoping for something more elegant due to complexity of my code something like `age!=null ? age : none`  I’ll wait few hours for someone with other idea and then I’ll mark your answer as answered... Vote up from me anyway :)